# How to get answer for a query which is asked from a parsed text?

Tags: python, nlp

A story (ie text data) and associated questions will be given as input. The python module should understand the story & questions then produce appropriate answer from the story. eg.
Story:
John, Steeve and Marc planned to go for a farewell party at evening together. 
However, John rang up to Marc and informed that, Steeve called him at 11:00 AM today and told that he couldn't join party as he is not doing well. So I will start at 7:00 PM, pick up you on the way.
Question:
What time did Steeve call?
Is Steeve doing good?
What time John start for the party?

Is it possible to program to get answer using NLP or any other tools in Python?

Comment: This question is too broad

Comment: Yes this question has a broad scope, but i think you might want to look into Machine Comprehension @SankarA